# Created mutliple CDN endpoints with the same origin hostname. How does the CDN work in this case/

Tags: azure, cdn

I have created two CDN endpoints in one CDN profile with the same web app as the origin hostname. In that case, how does my CDN work? Will it route the requests to both the CDN endpoints ??

Answer (score 0):

A CDN Profile is just a collection of CDN Endpoints. Endpoint is the real thing.

When you map a CDN endpoint (let's say -"**my-cdn-one.azureedge.net**" to a hostname (e.g. "**my.host.com**" - for each requested resource on the endpoint it will try to get the resource from the mapped host, for the first time. Then it will cache it for future requests on the same resource.

> https://my-cdn-one.azureedge.net/files/profile.jpg  >>> https://my.host.com/files/profile.jpg

The same thing will happen when you have multiple endpoints (in your case it is "2"). There will be two separate endpoints caching resources from the mapped host.

> https://my-cdn-**one**.azureedge.net/files/profile.jpg  >>> https://my.host.com/files/profile.jpg
>
> https://my-cdn-**two**.azureedge.net/files/profile.jpg  >>> https://my.host.com/files/profile.jpg

if you purge contents from one endpoint, the second endpoint will still have it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @priyankach: you can mark it as answer if that resolves your concern, thanks.